# I need an extraordinary algorithm about sorting and replacing in Java

Tags: java, sorting, replace

I need an algorithm like this:
For example when user entered "javacoder":

1. Find the first character by alphabet: a,
2. Find the last character by alphabet: v,
3. Replace these 2: "jvavcoder",
4. Find the second first character by alphabet: c,
5. Find the second last character by alphabet: r,
6. Replace these 2: "jvavrodec"

Do this for all letters and finally the output should be like this:
"evavrdojc"
How can i do this in Java? And I can't use arrays or replace methods.
Edit: I'm sorry im new at here so i don't know much about rules. Here is what i tried. It only sorts the characters from a sentence.

```
     import java.util.Scanner;

        public class Sorting

    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
            String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
            int i ; int k ; int j ; int l;
        for (i = 97 ; i <= 122; i++)
        {   for (k = 0 ; k < sentence.length() ; k++)
            {
                if (sentence.charAt(k) == i)
                {
                    char a = sentence.charAt(k);
                    System.out.print(a);
                }   
            }   
        }
        for (j = 122 ; j >= 97 ; j--)
        {   
            for (l = 0 ; l < sentence.length() ; l++)
                if (sentence.charAt(l) == j)
                {   
                    char b = sentence.charAt(l);
                    System.out.print(b);    
                } 

        }


    }
}
```

Here is the output for a sentence like "javacoder":

```
aacdejorvvrojedcaa
```

Comment: But @JavaCoder, you are the man to write write Java Code

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo code would be something like this ...

1. Do a Linear traversal and add all the characters into hashSet
2. Sort the hashSet and store it into arraylist or linkedHashset as hashset does not store insertion order
3. Replace the first character by last one and so on till you reach the middle of hashSet.

To sort the hashSet we need an arraylist or treeset.
To replace the character in string just use substring method.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comment. But I'm just new at Java so I don't know the methods that you've written. I need to do this with for loops just like I have written. But I couldn't think how to do that.

Comment: Well the logic in your code is wrong ...Which method in my solution do you want me to give a briefing?